# Angular2 Http.Post - How to view webapi response

Tags: json, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I'm new to Angular2/Typescript and I'm writing my first web application.

I'm trying to call a webapi using POST, it works, if I intercept the call using FIDDLER I can see the Json response.

Now, how I can log in the browser console the json ouput?

The code is this:

## code call

```
var s = this.myService.doSearch();
s.subscribe(
    data=> this.data = data,
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
);

console.log(s);
```

## service method

```
doSearch() {
var url = this.baseUrl;

return this.http.get(url)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

My question is: how and where I can view and manage the Json Output ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `console.log` it after the async code is finished:

```
var s = this.myService.doSearch();
s.subscribe(
    data=> {
          this.data = data;
          console.log(data);
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are debug or run your application in browser you can got to inspect and then move to the Network tab. In this tab select your POST Request and the go to the tab Response and voila there is your json Response

Edit:

```
To log all response data do this:
return this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => { console.log(data);})
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: thanks luka, this is exactly what I'm doing, but I what I need to do is logging the output using console.log command

Comment: Ah ok so you want to print your json response witch you got from the server into your console?

Comment: Yes, that is what I need

Comment: Edited my Question

Answer (score 1):

Try this this will print what you have in your returned observable .

```
var s = this.myService.doSearch();
s.subscribe(data=> {
       this.data = data;
       console.log(data);
       },
       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
);
```

Always remember If you want to get data from observable.you need to subscribe it.

you can't log it like this `console.log(s);` because s returns an observable. you should subscribe and refer those data inside the subscribe .